# TACACS+ Client Authentication on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

All of our network equipment is using TACACS for authentication. I've got an Ubuntu Server running 18.04.2 LTS and was wanting to utilize the existing TACACS servers for authentication to this server. So instead of creating local user accounts, the login requests get sent to the TACACS servers.

I'm only wanting to use the TACACS servers for authentication. I plan on using local authorization to determine what a user can/cannot do once authenticated. What's the best way to accomplish this? Most of the guides online provide steps on how to use an Ubuntu Server as a TACACS server, but I'm wanting to use it as a client.

Answer (score 1):

Password authentication on Linux uses PAM modules. The one for TACACS+ is called `pam_tacplus` and there appear to be two independent branches of it:

- https://github.com/jeroennijhof/pam_tacplus
- https://github.com/daveolson53/pam_tacplus

However, PAM only determines which username has authenticated, but it cannot retrieve that user's Unix account information (UID, GID, homedir, shell), which the system frequently requires also in contexts where it's impossible to perform interactive auth.

So unless the accounts are listed in /etc/passwd on the server, you'll also need an *nsswitch* module which can provide this data, e.g. libnss_ldap (nslcd) or libnss_sss (SSSD) if you have an LDAP server, or libnss_nis for NIS/YP.